# Grails Import Plugin Fails in Grails (rest plugin: compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0" and ":rest0.8")

Tags: eclipse, grails

I am trying to import plugin "rest-client-builder:2.0.0" and ":rest0.8". 
I am running grails 2.3.2

I add the grails plugin into BuildConfig.groovy 
=> compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0"

Then  i do "grails refresh-dependencies"

Then go into the grails controller in and try to import grails.plugin.rest-client-builder and this fails.. I am using eclipse..

I can see the controller listed in my directory though but eclipse doesnt load it:

```
Virals-MacBook-Pro:plugins viralcarpenter$ ls
cache-1.1.1         hibernate-3.6.10.3      resources-1.2.1         scaffolding-2.0.1       webxml-1.4.1
database-migration-1.3.8    jquery-1.10.2           rest-client-builder-2.0.0   tomcat-7.0.42
Virals-MacBook-Pro:plugins viralcarpenter$ ls rest*
RestClientBuilderGrailsPlugin.groovy    application.properties          plugin.xml
Virals-MacBook-Pro:plugins viralcarpenter$
```

Comment: What are you trying to import?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: According to ls statement result, **rest-client-builder-2.0.0** already installed. I think there are problem with **rest** plugin. Have you added **mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org/"** according to http://grails.org/plugin/rest

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are declared in **BuildConfig**.groovy, not in Bootstrap.groovy.

*BuildConfig.groovy:*

```
[...]

plugins{
    compile ':rest-client-builder:2.0.0'
}
```

You should check the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) of the plugin

Comment: sorry i mistyped.. i did put it in BuildConfig.groovy:

Comment: You could try running _grails> clean_ and launch the app again