# grails-rest-client-builder error bad organisation found

Tags: rest, grails

I am trying to use grails-rest-client-builder, but I am having trouble installing the plugin.

According to the documentation in
https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/
The readme instructions say "**Edit BuildConfig.groovy and add the following dependency:**"

**compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0"**

Note that the readme instructions imply that this should be under **dependencies** and not under **plugins**?

I have added the following to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
…
compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0"
…
}
```

However I get the following errors:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: rest-client-builder-2.0.0.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/tags/RELEASE_2_0_0/rest-client-builder-2.0.0.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'
```

I did see the post:
[Grails Import Plugin Fails in Grails (rest plugin: compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.0" and ":rest0.8")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984466/grails-import-plugin-fails-in-grails-rest-plugin-compile-rest-client-builder)
but I think that problem is different.
thank you,
-J

Comment: I was in an impression that we still need v1.0.3 of plugin for Grails v2.2.* in plugin section. The newest version is compatible with Grails 2.3.*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grails pliugins like the rest client builder you need to add it to the plugin section not the dependency section.

Here is an example [BuildConfig (see highlighted line).](https://github.com/beckje01/example-grails-badid/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L56)

Comment: Yes, it does need to be in the plugins section, and dmahapatro was correct as well, I upgraded to Grails 2.3.6 and the problem went away. Thank you!